# serializeJSON between ColdFusion 8 and ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-10

I have a function that returns a JSON string, and ColdFusion 10 returns a slightly different value than ColdFusion 8.

In CF10, I get

```
{"ZIPCODE":90210,"PHONE":"(555) 382-6630","LAT":83,"DISTANCE":74,"NAME":"Pueblo, CO","ADDRESS":"6830 Meddley Drive","LONG":104}
```

but in CF8, I get this

```
{\"DISTANCE\":74,\"LAT\":83,\"ZIPCODE\":90210,\"NAME\":\"Pueblo, CO\",\"PHONE\":\"(555) 382-6630\",\"ADDRESS\":\"6830 Medley Drive\",\"LONG\":104.}
```

For the function, I have `returnformat` set to `JSON` and use `serializeJSON()` for the return value. I'm calling the function via jQuery's `$.ajax` method with `dataType` set to `JSON`

The backslashes from CF8 are causing errors in the javascript used to parse the data. Why is this happening, and is there a workaround?

Comment: The CFC will automatically return it in JSON format, so calling `serializeJSON()` JSON-ifies the JSON. Which effectively escapes all the special characters with backslashes. Try it without calling `serializeJSON()`.

Comment: @imthepitts - (Edit) Yep, [no need to use both](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2008/6/3/Be-careful-with-returnFormat-and-JSON). (You could even omit both and just use the url parameter `?returnformat=json` to specify you want the result in json format). Anyway, you should write that up as an answer, btw.

Comment: I wonder why this isn't a problem with CF10 ...

Comment: Well if it does not "double-serialize" (as the code is instructing CF to do) then they obviously added some logic as a protection measure. CF must detect whether the result is already serialized, and if so it returns the result "as-is".

Answer (score 0):

my guess would cf10 is automatically returning it in json format and cf8 isn't

Comment: No, based on the results CF10 is smart enough to recognize the code is unintentionally serializing the result twice (ie using both `serializeJSON()` **and** `returnformat="json"`) so it must ignore one of them. CF8 does not have that feature, so it serializes the result twice.